# "In page" or "on page", which preposition?

Tags: prepositions

"Statement 2 in page 172" or "statement 2 on page 172"?

I write a mathematical book and need to refer to certain page of another mathematical book.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

From Longman Dictionary of Contemporary English ([see here](http://www.ldoceonline.com/dictionary/page)), the correct preposition is 'on',
Example:

> The full address is given on page 15.

Answer (score 0):

I would have said the following

> You are writing a book on mathematics which references Statement 2 on
>   page 172 'of' another mathematical book.

Comment: Would you please provide an explanation as to why you think that sentence is your suggestion?