# What is proper English -- "In 5 pages" or "On 5 pages"?

Tags: word-choice, prepositions

Could someone please explain what preposition is accurate in context of a page section where the total quantity of pages in a document is specified?

I suspect that one may use "on" in a sentence such as "Use red font on five pages and use green on five pages that follow." Not when one's intention is to inform a reader of a total amount of pages he or she would have to deal with.

Comment: Related but not a duplicate: [“In page” or “on page”, which preposition?](https://ell.stackexchange.com/q/107305/9161) and [How to refer to pages: at / on / in?](https://ell.stackexchange.com/q/251647/9161)

Comment: Thank you! Checked those out prior to writing this post. However, they did not answer my question.

Comment: I linked them just in case someone found your question, but they were looking for the answer to those other questions. When someone links a question in the comments, it shows up in the right sidebar (or at the bottom of the page if you are on a device with a small screen). That’s why I stated that they were related, but not potential duplicates.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your intuition is correct. **On *X* pages** is used to describe the content contained within a single page or range of pages. **In *X* pages** is used to describe a number of pages. So:

> *In* ten pages, describe your activities over the summer. Use red font *on* the first five pages and green font *on* the next five.

Comment: I don't know why this was downvoted, perhaps the downvoter believes that one can also say "Write your essay **in** [X] pages” ? But it's +1 from me in anycase.